# Docker Alpine Failed building wheel for scipy

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm getting some weird errors while running

```
docker-compose build
```

for my dockerized application,

Before, when my dockerfile was like this:

```
 FROM python:2

 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

 RUN mkdir /code

 EXPOSE 80

 WORKDIR /code

 ADD requirements.txt /code/

 RUN pip2 install -r requirements.txt

 ADD . /code/
```

I hadnt this kind of error, and the application was running perfectly, 
But to reduce storage use, I decided to use alpine, so I changed my Dockerfile:

FROM python:2-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 RUN apk --update add --no-cache g++

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

ADD requirements.txt /code/
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /code/

but for that I'm getting Errors, I know that I have to add some things but I dont know what exactly,

for every library in requirements.txt I'm getting this error:

```
Failed building wheel for scipy
```

And in the end of the build, I'm getting this error

```
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: check logs of container

Comment: If using the Alpine base image is causing problems, and you need to install a (large) C toolchain in it anyways, you're not saving that much space and I might switch back to the standard image (that you know works).

Comment: @DavidMaze C toolchain is not needed for runtime, just to build dependencies.

Comment: @JakubJirutka So what to do?

Comment: Can't we add the C toolchain and then remove it after build?

Comment: Any resolution to this? @Yahia